# How to determine if three numbers are equal

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

Using strictly bitwise operations, how would I determine if three numbers are equal. So far, I have the code shown below, but it doesn't work for edge cases like 0x80000000,0x7fffffff,0x7fffffff.

```
int isEqualThree(int x, int y, int z) {
    int first = x ^ y;
    int second = first ^ z;
    int third = second ^ x;
    int final = !third;
    return final;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this

```
int check(int a,int b,int c)
{
    return !((a^b)|(b^c));
}
```

Since there is no constraint specified on number of operators to be used, if ! is not allowed then this can be a solution too considering 32 bit numbers,using only bitwise operators

```
int check(int a,int b,int c)
{
  int d;
  d=(a^b)|(b^c); 
  d=~d; 
  return ((d>>31&1)&(d>>30&1)&(d>>29&1)&(d>>28&1)&(d>>27&1)&(d>>26&1)&(d>>25&1)&(d>>24&1)&(d>>23&1)&(d>>22&1)&(d>>21&1)&(d>>20&1)&(d>>19&1)&(d>>18&1)&(d>>17&1)&(d>>16&1)&(d>>15&1)&(d>>14&1)&(d>>13&1)&(d>>12&1)&(d>>11&1)&(d>>10&1)&(d>>9&1)&(d>>8&1)&(d>>7&1)&(d>>6&1)&(d>>5&1)&(d>>4&1)&(d>>3&1)&(d>>2&1)&(d>>1&1)&(d&1));
```

}

Comment: `!` isn't a bitwise operation.

Comment: @FredLarson isn't it equivalent to xor with all ones?

Comment: @Max: No, but `~` is.

Comment: I'll try to give a solution without ! in few min.

Comment: @JimMischel it doesnt fail. it works fine. i have even coded it

Comment: @JimMischel `~((0^1)|(1^0))==~(1|1)==~1==0`

Comment: @Max thankyou. but i found that ~ cant be used like that. doesnt work for inputs like 1 2 3. so let it be ! for now.

Comment: Well, this answer doesn't fulfil the requirements and the previous version was unable to do the work... Anyhow, excluding the arguments and curly braces lines, one line of code, and 100% fail rate of semicolons, kek

Comment: @ThoAppelsin ya now i have added solution without using !. that worked

Comment: @Rohith this approach is going to get a bit long winded particularly on a 64 bit int platform. I have added an alternate way to address the need to not use `!` as a separate answer.

Comment: @abligh ya right your method is shorter way to check whether a number is zero. thankyou

Answer (score 4):

Building on [@LearningC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22176619/584676) of

```
int check(int a,int b,int c)
{
    return !((a^b)|(b^c));
}
```

If you don't want the `!`:

```
int check(int a,int b,int c)
{
    unsigned int d = (unsigned int) ((a^b)|(b^c)); /* 0 if equal, non-zero otherwise */
    d |= d>>32; /* set bit n if bit n+32 set - only needed for 64 bit int platforms */
    d |= d>>16; /* set bit n if bit n+16 set */
    d |= d>>8; /* set bit n if bit n+8 set */
    d |= d>>4; /* set bit n if bit n+4 set */
    d |= d>>2; /* set bit n if bit n+2 set */
    d |= d>>1; /* set bit n if bit n+1 set */
    return (int)((~d) &1);
}
```

which I believe is a little simpler than his.

Comment: +1 for the `d |= d>>32` realizing various `int` sizes.

Answer (score 1):

```
int isEqualThree(int x, int y, int z) {
    int a=(x^y);
    int b=(y^z);

    return !(a|b);

}
```

`xor` of two numbers are zero only when all the bits of the numbers are identical. So from above, if either `a` or `b` is non-zero then it implies that at least one number is different from the other two. So in that case return zero else one, which explains `return !(a|b);`.

Comment: "Using only bitwise operations." You can't use an `if`.

Comment: I think the spirit of the question is to formulate a predicated series of bitwise operations, so that would preclude the use of branches.

Comment: No I cant use an **if**, and I dont know how to make one using bitwise operations

Comment: `!` isn't a bitwise operation.

Comment: My mistake. I was sure you had `a=!(x^y)`.

Comment: The answer has no explanations, but it seems to be the best one using only bitwise operators, so +1

Comment: Not sure how "which explains return ~(a|b);" explains `return !(a|b);`

Answer (score 0):

If == is acceptable, there's also

int check( int x, int y, int z )
{
return (x | y | z) == (x & y & z);
}